# Are heating foils resistors?

Tags: resistors, stm32, embedded, actuator, heater

In my project I need to use some heating foils to warm a chamber up to a certain temperature. I would like to use polyimide or polyester [heating foils](https://www.conrad.ch/de/p/thermo-tech-polyimid-heizfolie-selbstklebend-24-v-dc-24-v-ac-75-w-schutzart-ipx4-l-x-b-155-mm-x-75-mm-1594198.html).

If these heating foils act as resistors, can I put them in series or parallel if I need to obtain a certain wattage?

I might need to develop a kind of thermostat using an STM32 microcontroller. How can I drive these heating foils? Can I use some MOSFET switch?

Before I select the heating foils, I would like to be sure how to to handle these actuators and then I would like to make a PCB to power all the elements.

It might be a stupid question, but I can't find this information on Google or in manuals.

Answer (score 4):

Some are simple resistors, others have PTC characteristics. That means they heat up themselves but their resistance increases with temperature so they reach a defined equilibrium temperature. Pretty much the same as incandescent lighbulbs but at much lower temperatures.

Simple resistors you can put in series or in parallel, but the PTC ones are a bit tricky. Those in series must be heat-coupled as otherwise the hotter one will limit the current through the colder one so that one won't heat up. But the best idea is not to put PTC heaters in series as you can't have that problem then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are just large resistors (the particular type you linked at least; others are PTCs as Janka mentioned). Connecting them in series or parallel is perfectly fine. You can switch them on or off with a MOSFET. Make sure to use a logic-level MOSFET (rated for 3.3V gate voltage) if you want to control the MOSFET directly with your STM32.

Keep in mind that you need double the voltage if you connect two heating elements in series, or double the current if you connect them in parallel.

Note also that these particular heating elements are not self-regulating, which means that there's no limit on how hot they can get if they're not adequately cooled or regulated. If you let them get too hot, they burn out. This should not be a problem in your application, though, since you're planning to build a thermostat anyway (which turns them off if they get too hot).

The way these polyimide heating elements are (or at least can be) manufactured is quite interesting, too: The polyimide foil gets burnt with a laser, which turns its surface into a graphite-like conductive material wherever the laser hits it.